# shell script executing several shell scripts for cron

Tags: shell, cron

I am new to using Linux shell scripts and cron.  If I run the pubspg1.sh from a command line - it runs just fine but when running it with cron - nothing happens.  Maybe I do not have the script setup properly to run in cron?  Note: /path... is the full path to the shell script.

On cron, I have this:

```
30 22 * * 2 sh /path... /pubspg1.sh
```

pubspg1.sh script looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

/usr/bin/sh /path... /pub1pg1.sh

/usr/bin/sh /path... /pub2pg1.sh

/usr/bin/sh /path... /pub3pg1.sh

/usr/bin/sh /path... /pub4pg1.sh
```

Comment: It should be #!/usr/bin/bash (before editing your shell script make sure /usr/bin/bash exists)

Comment: You can check if "sh" and "bash" are really on the same paths. hit "whereis sh" and "whereis bash"

Comment: I did check the paths before writing the scripts... both are under /usr/bin.  I used "which sh" and "which bash".

Comment: try adding "touch /tmp/test.txt" in pubspg1.sh as a first command. restart the cron service and see if you get test.txt created in /tmp. At this point you will at least know whether main script is running or not.

Comment: I am not sure if this helps or not, but when I create a script like above with only one entry and do the cron line as above... it works.

Comment: That's good. Now we can be sure that problem lies in executing pub1pg1.sh,pub2pg1.sh etc. try modifying your command as "/usr/bin/sh /path... /pub1pg1.sh &> /tmp/out.txt". That will dump any error messages int /tmp/out.txt. let us know what goes inside out.txt

Answer (score 0):

1. Make sure that you have at least one blank line after your last crontab entry.
2. Change sh to bash
3. Make sure that your path doesn't contain special characters that need to be escaped (e.g., %)

Answer (score 0):

1. You need to change `/usr/bin/bash` to `%path_to_SH%/sh` in script if u are using sh (you can check that pass by typing `which sh`) and then you need to remove all `/usr/bin/` from your script;
2. Try to check permissions to execute that script for rights;
3. You can do your script executable (chmod a+x %script%) and then just put full path to it without `sh`.

P.S. And be sure, that u're running cron-daemon or cron.service (if u are using systemd)

Comment: 1. So, I would change it to /usr/bin/sh (path I got when typing which sh)
2. Permissions are 0755
3. Are you talking about cron here?

Comment: Is this what you are saying:

#!/usr/bin/sh

sh /path... /pub1pg1.sh

sh /path... /pub2pg1.sh

sh /path... /pub3pg1.sh

Comment: @LindaSabo Just try to begin every entry with `sh`, without path to it. And if u said, that only one entry is OK in cron, then try to use && after every script, if every script returns 0. But if one of this chain will fail it would crush the rest of commands.

Comment: Remember, I am not too versed with this...
Would I add && inside each script being called... at the end of each script?